# Apache Rewrite to Remove PHP Extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to eliminate PHP extensions using the Apache rewrite engine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) $1.php [L]
```

This works, but only assuming all the files are in the base directory. Here are a couple of success and fail results:

```
myphpfile > myphpfile.php
directory/myphpfile > directory.php (not correct)
```

I would like the second one to produce this result:

```
directory/myphpfile > directory/myphpfile.php (correct)
```

I did try both of the following, but without success:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)/^([a-zA-Z\-]+) $1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule directory\/^([a-zA-Z\-]+) directory\/$1.php [L]
```

Neither solution is ideal. The first would handle only one directory deep (workable, but not great). The second would require hardcoding each directory. Neither of the above worked though so I suppose it doesn't matter.

Anyone have any ideas? Essentially, I just want to eradicate the PHP extension in a multi-directory infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

To add `.php` across directories you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```